# R spread value evenly over years

Tags: r

I have a list of values that I want to spread evenly over multiple years in R.  I think I'm missing something right in front of me.

I have:

```
#Create dataframe
df <- data.frame(product=rep(c('A','B')),
                 QTY = c('45', '90'))

#Check
df

# List Years
years <- c(2022:2027)
```

I would like to spread the values of each product evenly over the years listed ending with something like

| Product | QTY | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 6.4 | 2022 |
| A | 6.4 | 2023 |
| A | 6.4 | 2024 |
| A | 6.4 | 2025 |
| A | 6.4 | 2026 |
| A | 6.4 | 2027 |
| B | 12.9 | 2022 |
| B | 12.9 | 2023 |
| B | 12.9 | 2024 |
| B | 12.9 | 2025 |
| B | 12.9 | 2026 |
| B | 12.9 | 2027 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps - divide the 'QTY' by the `length` of 'years' (+ 1) and use `crossing` to expand the data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    mutate(QTY = as.numeric(QTY)/(length(years)+1)) %>%
    crossing(Year = years)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 3
   product   QTY  Year
   <chr>   <dbl> <int>
 1 A        6.43  2022
 2 A        6.43  2023
 3 A        6.43  2024
 4 A        6.43  2025
 5 A        6.43  2026
 6 A        6.43  2027
 7 B       12.9   2022
 8 B       12.9   2023
 9 B       12.9   2024
10 B       12.9   2025
11 B       12.9   2026
12 B       12.9   2027
```

Comment: I miscalculated when I made the example but this is what I need just without the +1.  Thank was quick... one of these days ill get the hang of this.  Thank You,